# How to design BottomNavigationView with Scrollview and LinearLayout

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

I want to add BottomNavigationView on bottom.Also, I have LinearLayout because I have to use ScroolView but I can not fixed BottomNavaigationView on bottom.In my design BottomNavigationView can be scrolling.How can I design that BottomNavigationView is fixed ? I am open mind another design method , I need ScrollView ,Buttons and BottomNavigationView.Here is my xml design.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text=""
                android:textStyle="bold" />


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/logoHarita"

                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"

                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:src="@drawable/magazine_last"/>


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/sonSayiDergi"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                style="@style/btnStyleSeagull"
                android:text="SON" />


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/eDergiler"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                style="@style/btnStyleSeagull"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:text="DERGİLER"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/ozelSayilar"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                style="@style/btnStyleSeagull"
                android:text="SAYILAR"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/makaleSorgulama"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                style="@style/btnStyleSeagull"
                android:text="SORGULAMA"
                android:textSize="18sp"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/dergiYonetimKurulu"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                style="@style/btnStyleSeagull"
                android:text="KURULU"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/dergiBilimKurulu"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                style="@style/btnStyleSeagull"
                android:text="KURULU"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/makaleYazımEsasları"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                style="@style/btnStyleSeagull"
                android:text="MAKALE YAZIM ESASLARI"
                android:textSize="18sp" />




            <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
                android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"

                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimary2"
                app:itemIconTint="#ffffff"
                app:itemTextColor="#ffffff"
                app:menu="@menu/navigationbar" />


        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

[BottomNavigationView is not fixed , it can be scrolling.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2LYY.jpg)

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot or drawing of how you want your bottom navigation to look like? It is not recommended to use bottom navigation when there are too many items.

Comment: I added the picture.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ScrollView
    android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text=""
            android:textStyle="bold" />


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/logoHarita"

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"

            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/magazine_last" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/sonSayiDergi"
            style="@style/btnStyleSeagull"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="SON"
            android:textSize="18sp" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/eDergiler"
            style="@style/btnStyleSeagull"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="DERGİLER"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/ozelSayilar"
            style="@style/btnStyleSeagull"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="SAYILAR"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/makaleSorgulama"
            style="@style/btnStyleSeagull"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="SORGULAMA"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/dergiYonetimKurulu"
            style="@style/btnStyleSeagull"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="KURULU"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/dergiBilimKurulu"
            style="@style/btnStyleSeagull"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="KURULU"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/makaleYazımEsasları"
            style="@style/btnStyleSeagull"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="MAKALE YAZIM ESASLARI"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimary2"
    app:itemIconTint="#ffffff"
    app:itemTextColor="#ffffff"
    app:menu="@menu/navigationbar" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Check This answer . I hope this will help you

Comment: Thanks.It helps a lot.

Comment: if this answer help you then give vote . to this answer thanks

Comment: I have not enough reputation , so I can not vote :) thanks.

Comment: important things for me were android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" and android:layout_gravity="bottom". Thanks for the answer btw

Answer (score 0):

You should place the BottomNavigationView outside of your scrollview.

For example:

```
<ConstraintLayout>
  <ScrollView/>
  <BottomNavigation/>
</ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: it does not work.How can define other layout ? What about Main Layout ?

Comment: You should use your scrollview and your bottom navigation at the same level inside a layout that contains them.